# JUnit assertEquals failure

Tags: java, junit

I have the following test method which keeps failing:

```
/**
 * Test of averageResult method, of class MonthlyPayroll.
 */
public void testAverageResult() {
    System.out.println("averageResult");
    double[] MonthlySales = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int howMany = 6;
    double expResult = 6.5;
    double epsilon = 1;
    double result = MonthlyPayroll.averageResult(MonthlySales, howMany);
    assertEquals(expResult, result, epsilon);
    // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
    fail("The test case is a prototype.");
}
```

The method works fine, when I debug the test, result and expResult are equal, but I get the following failure message:

```
compile-test-single:
Testsuite: pkgbmc.MonthlyPayrollTest
averageResult
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.109 sec

------------- Standard Output ---------------
averageResult
------------- ---------------- ---------------
Testcase: testAverageResult(pkgbmc.MonthlyPayrollTest): FAILED
The test case is a prototype.
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: The test case is a prototype.
at pkgbmc.MonthlyPayrollTest.testAverageResult(MonthlyPayrollTest.java:61)
```

Anyone any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't get it: you're calling `fail(...)` and ask why you get a failing test?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The call to fail

```
fail("The test case is a prototype.");
```

makes the test fail.

Note that in any IDE I know of you could have (double)clicked on the line

```
at pkgbmc.MonthlyPayrollTest.testAverageResult(MonthlyPayrollTest.java:61)
```

to get you exactly to the problematic line, which is NOT your `assertEquals`

Comment: There's even a big *TODO* in the code: "remove the default call to fail"  ;)

Comment: oh ok, didn't realise that's what happened, literally looking at testing in Java, and Java in generally, for the first time today, and just sort of trying to work it out as I go along. Thanks.

Comment: @ailinmcc666 hint: look at the generated error message which contains file and line information of where the error happened. I assume line 61 is the one with `fail(...)`.

Comment: @ailinmcc666 Everybody here has been that idiot at some point. Those with high rep more often.